# How to make Javascript not to overwrite the previous function?

Tags: javascript

```
<!-- inEar -->
$("#inEear ul li a").ready(function(){
    thisBlock = $("#dueceBlock");
    maxWidth = 280; /*controls max width of the block*/
    minWidth = 180; /*controls min widht of the block*/


    $("#inEar ul li a").hover(
      function(){
        $(thisBlock).animate({width: minWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth+"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:300}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth-"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:100}, { queue:false, duration:500 });

        thisBlock = this;
      }
    );
})
<!-- inEar end-->

<!-- onEar -->
$(".onEarLink").ready(function(){
    thisBlock = $("#chillBlock");
    maxWidth = 280; /*controls max width of the block*/
    minWidth = 180; /*controls min widht of the block*/


    $(".onEarLink").hover(
      function(){
        $(thisBlock).animate({width: minWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth+"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:300}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth-"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:100}, { queue:false, duration:500 });

        thisBlock = this;
      }
    );
})
<!-- onEar end-->

<!-- overEar -->
$(".overEarLink").ready(function(){
    thisBlock = $("#heroBlock");
    maxWidth = 400; /*controls max width of the block*/
    minWidth = 100; /*controls min widht of the block*/


    $(".overEarLink").hover(
      function(){
        $(thisBlock).animate({width: minWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth+"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:300}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth-"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:100}, { queue:false, duration:500 });

        thisBlock = this;
      }
    );
})
```

---

My problem is: my third function (.overEarLink) keeps overwriting the first function (#inEar ul li a) and second function (.onEarLink). This is not what I want. I want to make three function calls different parts and controls their own animation. I didn't understand why even though I specified the different name of each function, why the third function still overwrites the first function and the second function.

Thanks for everybody's help.

---

Adding var works, I appreciate for your answers. However, I used var on maxWidth and minWidth too. However, same thing happened, the third var overwrites the first var and the second var again. 
Here is the code for it:

```
$("#overEar ul li a").ready(function(){
   var thisBlock = $("#heroBlock");
   var maxWidth = 358; /*controls max width of the block*/
   var minWidth = 180;

   var thisBlock = $("#reverbBlock"); /*controls min widht of the block*/
   var maxWidth = 340; 
   var minWidth = 180;

   var thisBlock = $("#solosBlock"); 
   var maxWidth = 402; 
   var minWidth = 180;

    $("#overEar ul li a").hover(
      function(){
        $(thisBlock).animate({width: minWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth+"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:300}, { queue:false, duration:500 });
    $(this).animate({width: maxWidth-"px"}, {specialEasing:'easeInOutBounce', duration:100}, { queue:false, duration:500 });

        thisBlock = this;
      }
    );
})
```

Thanks for everybody's answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use *local variables*, so that each function has separate variables from the other functions. For example, change this:

```
    thisBlock = $("#heroBlock");
    maxWidth = 400; /*controls max width of the block*/
    minWidth = 100; /*controls min widht of the block*/
```

to this:

```
    var thisBlock = $("#heroBlock");
    var maxWidth = 400; /*controls max width of the block*/
    var minWidth = 100; /*controls min widht of the block*/
```

The `var` keyword restricts the variable's [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) to the specific function in which it's declared.

Comment: Ruakh, thanks so much for your answers. It works now. But, I have another problem comes up.

Comment: ruakh, I posted another problem under the original problem, are you able to take look? Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @YifanChen: Did you post your actual code? It doesn't make sense to me; you have a single function where you set `thisBlock` and `maxWidth` and `minWidth`, and then -- before you do anything with them -- you immediately overwrite them with different values of `thisBlock` and `maxWidth` and `minWidth`.

Comment: This is the part of actual code. Yes. That's what my problem is, I don't want the last value keeps overwriting the previous the value of thisBLock. So, I signed different values of thisBlock like var thisBlock = $("heroBlock")/$("reverbBlock")/$("solousBlock"), and gave the different minWidth and maxWidth. However, somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: @YifanChen: I take it that you're new to programming? I recommend you find a book or tutorial to learn from; that will be much easier, and much more effective, than trying to learn piecemeal by assembling scripts without really understanding them . . . :-/

Comment: ruakh, yes. I am newbie at this. Thanks so much for your recommendation.